# How can you dynamically set a variable in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I'm looking to use a text input to set the value of a variable that's in Razor syntax. Is this even possible?

So far I can only hard code a value of a variable that's in Razor syntax.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

Pages and Views (aka. cshtml pages with razor syntax) only renders for once and respond them as static html contents.

As long as the page is loaded at the front end, the razor page has finished its work, and the request scope is disposed. Thus no status would remain at the back end.

This is called one-way data binding and is how MVC works, the data gets updated by a new request to a controller and the the controller update the data and return a new Page or View rendered.

If you wish to keep the razor page alive while the page is displayed and handle user interaction with C# instead of Javascript, you have to use [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) which is a part of ASP.NET Core 3.0.

To [get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) you need to install .NET Core 3.0 SDK with [Visual Studio 2019 **16.3**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) or the latest [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

With blazor, you can make two-way data binding like this:

```
<h1>@_value</h1>

<input @bind="_value" @bind:event="oninput" />

@code
{
    private string _value;
}
```

The content in the `h1` element, the `_value` field, and the value of the input element would be binded in real time to reflect any changes of each other.